# How to fill the entire screen with an image so that rounded edges get included too?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a splash screen. The image on the background (behind the face with a cap) should fill the entire screen but it doesn't. There are insets on the left and right side of the screen. My guess is; since I'm testing on Samsung Galaxy S9, rounded edges of the screen is not getting included in MediaQuery.of(context).size. I've tried playing with removeViewPadding and removeViewInsets but I couldn't make it work. What should I do?

Current state of splash screen:
[image]

My Widget build() function:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
//        width: MediaQuery.of(context).removeViewInsets(
//         removeLeft: true,
//         removeRight: true,
//         removeBottom: true,
//         removeTop: true
//        ).size.width,
//        height: MediaQuery.of(context).removeViewInsets(
//          removeLeft: true,
//          removeRight: true,
//          removeBottom: true,
//          removeTop: true
//        ).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              Assets.splash_screen_background,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
            Image.asset(
              Assets.logo,
              scale: 4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you tried BoxFit.cover?

Answer (score 0):

try giving double.infinity it stretches height to the maximum possible height of the canvas or parent widget

```
Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height:double.infinity,
    child: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          Assets.splash_screen_background,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        Image.asset(
          Assets.logo,
          scale: 4,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```